# Simple Form Association Collection: How to exclude an id from a collection - Rails4

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, simple-form

I would like to know how to exclude a specific id from a simple form collection.

- recruiter_A has a list of created job adverts [advert_A, advert_B, advert_C]
- recruiter_A selects advert_A from their list of created job adverts and successfully sends an invite to jobseeker_A to apply for advert_A
- recruiter_A wants to invite jobseeker_A again to apply for another job created by them
- recruiter_A should only see the list of created job adverts [advert_B, advert_C]

> > question: how do i exclude the id of advert_A using simple form
> >     association collection?
>
> ```
> <div><%= f.association :advert, collection: Advert.where(recruiter: @recruiter), prompt: "select an advert",
> > label: "Advert" %></div>
> ```

your help would be much appreciated.

schema

```
  create_table "invites", force: true do |t|
    t.integer  "advert_id"
    t.integer  "jobseeker_id"
    t.integer  "recruiter_id"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end
```

models

```
advert has_many invites
jobseeker has_many invites
recruiter has_many invites

invite belongs to advert
invite belongs to jobseeker
invite belongs to recruiter

recruiter has_many adverts
advert belongs_to recruiter
```

invites/_form.html.erb

```
<%= simple_form_for Invite.new do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_notification %>

  <div class="form-inputs">
    <div><%= f.association :advert, collection: Advert.where(recruiter: @recruiter), prompt: "select an advert", label: "Advert" %></div>

    <%= f.hidden_field :jobseeker_id, value: jobseeker.id %>
    <%= f.hidden_field :recruiter_id, value: @recruiter.id  %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-actions">
    <%= f.button :submit, "Send Invite" %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```